# What are the features of the Group module versus Organic Group module?

Tags: organic-groups

To create groups in Drupal we have at this moment the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module and the [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module.

From the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module page:

> The Group module allows you to create arbitrary collections of your
>   content and users on your site and grant access control permissions on
>   those collections

From the [Organic Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module page:

> Enable users to create and manage their own 'groups'. Each group can
>   have subscribers, and maintains a group home page where subscribers
>   communicate amongst themselves.

What are the features of [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) versus [Organic Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/og)?

Comment: Isn't this an opinion-based question ?

Comment: @mchar I don't think this because this is based in facts. You can say Group have this functionalities, but Organic Group don't have it. So with Group you can do this kind of things but not with Organic Group.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, I was just asking, I didn't know that modules comparison is accepted, now I know!

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer : have you noticed that your question here also illustrates the 4th bullet I mentioned in the "disadvantages" of my answer? Check the revision history of your question ...

Comment: _Pros and cons_ could be subjective when talking about something, but it doesn't seem subjective when talking of a module's features. Maybe the question can be rewritten to avoid using that term.

Comment: @kiamlaluno thanks, I make a edit, now is better?

Comment: That is perfect. At least users should not add an answer like _I prefer X because it allows me to..._. The features a module has is not a subjective list.

Comment: @kiamlaluno yes, that's have sense ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## About

The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module allows for creating arbitrary collections of your content and users on your site, and grant access control permissions on those collections. It is available as of D7, and has a D8 version also. It is designed to be an alternative to [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og).

**Organic Groups** allows content itself to be groups, which isn't always what people want. It relies on an entity reference field to keep track of the ties between a group (node, term, ...) and its content (node, term, user, ...)

**Group** instead creates groups as entities, making them fully fieldable, extensible and exportable. Every group can have users, roles and permissions attached to it (refer to "[What are the various roles supported by the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197493)" for more details about that). Groups can also act as a parent of any type of entity. Group provides an extensive API to attach entities to groups.

## Advantages of Group as compared to OG

- **Group** started in D7 only, taking full advantage of entities introduced in D7.
- **Group** doesn't 'abuse' nodes by adding custom fields to them in order to make the module work.
- **Group** does not allow you to have per-group roles or permissions. These are instead defined on the group type. So group types, group roles and permissions are configuration instead of content. Because of this approach, group types and roles exportable (with or without Features).
- **Organic Groups** is commonly perceived as a huge module, which carries a lot of "legacy" from pre-D7 releases and makes it tougher to ever get upgraded to D8.
- A D8 version of **Group** is already available (not so for Organic Groups).

## Disadvantages of Group as compared to OG

- As of today, **Group** only has alfa / beta releases (not any official release).
- Even though some say it is self documenting, I think it is not (maybe because I don't want to digest the source code to find out what this module can do ...).
- Not a lot of documentation available.
- As of today, there is no [group](/questions/tagged/group) tag on drupal.SE, though there is an [organic-groups](/questions/tagged/organic-groups) tag, and there are already [quite a few Group specific questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq%20%22group%20module%22%20-%22field%20group%22%20-[organic-groups]). Anybody interested in creating it (again), feel free to reuse my previously approved [tag wiki](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76965) and/or [tag excerpt](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76966) (no need for credits ...).

## Integration with various modules

The Group module integrates with various other (popular) modules, including:

- [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2603136), as illustrated in the answer to the question "[How to bulk assign existing content to a group created with the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197489/)".
- [Views](https://www.drupal.org/node/2540994), as illustrated in the answer to the question "[How to show the content of a group on the group page when using the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197552/)".
- [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/node/2343509).

The beauty, IMO, of these integrations are that they are more or less out-of-the box (not dozens of extra modules needed to make those integrations work).

Refer to [Integrations with other modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2603130) and its "Related issues" about other modules for which integrations already exist, or are in the pipeline.

## Resources

- [Community documentation for the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972).
- Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s)".
- Podcast "[Using the Group module as an Alternative to Organic Groups in Drupal 7 and 8](https://modulesunraveled.com/podcast/158-using-group-module-alternative-organic-groups-drupal-7-and-8-kristiaan-van-den-eynde)".
- [What are the alternatives for the Organic groups module?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/164)

## What people say about the Group module

Similar to what you see in the **Group** issue queue: most (if not all) people who know about **Group** just love it ...

Answer (score 5):

There is an article that comes from being published named: [GROUP FOR DRUPAL](http://www.agiledrop.com/blog/group-drupal?utm_source=The%20Weekly%20Drop&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=The_Weekly_Drop_Issue_256_09_08_2016)

The author says about group:

- Simple

> Groups should be like content types. I want different kinds of groups
>   with different fields, roles and permissions. That’s exactly how Group
>   handles it.

- Group content

> Basically anything you attach to the group can be fieldable. Another
>   interesting thing about the relationship entity that sits between the
>   group and the actual user/content is, that if you delete it from the
>   Group interface, you are not deleting the content, but the linking
>   entity instead, so the content (or user/entity/whatever) is left
>   unchanged.

- Powerful

> Every group type has their own group content types and every one of
>   them has configurable permissions and fields.
>
> Out of the box, Group integrates with Views, Rules, i18n, Title and
>   I’m sure much more is coming. Built on top of Entity, API Group
>   provides all of its benefits to developers.

And as conclusion:

> There is no doubt that Group is here to take the place of OG. It has
>   everything that OG provides plus all the things that were missing. All
>   brought in a neat UI, where you can configure so much without being a
>   coder.
>
> The only downside of Group I can think of currently is the state of
>   the module. It’s currently marked as alpha, but seeing the growing
>   number of contributors and downloads can only mean the development
>   speed is increasing. It’s also hard to expect finding a lot of answers
>   online, because Group is a very young module. Nevertheless, given very
>   good response rates on the module’s issue queues I would say that
>   writing a ticket is your best bet if you need any help.

**EDIT:** Another god article to read is: [Building Community Sites in Drupal 8: A Guide To D8 Modules For Community Support Sites](https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/building-community-sites-drupal-8-guide-d8-modules-community-support-sites?utm_source=drupal-newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=drupal-newsletter-20170706)

Comment: Didn't know about this article!

Comment: "It has everything that OG provides plus all the things that were missing" For what I understood, permissions are defined site-wise, not group-wise. If you want each group admin to define the permissions for the content in its "own" group, you can't in group, but you can in OG.