# How to configure access for creating a custom LMS?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, organic-groups

I am looking to create a LMS either in an existing Drupal install.

Anonymous users can browse course information and also preview certain Modules & Slides (see below). They will be able to buy access to a Course and then view the all the Course content. There will be a multiple different Courses, each need to be purchased separately at different prices.

Course hierarchy:

- Course > Module(s) > Topic(s) > Slide(s)
- Course is what the user will pay for access
- Modules and Topics are the only for categorisation and may only have a Small description
- Preview content will be by only a select few Modules per Course - being able to see the slides within chosen module
- Slides are where the learning content is - mostly videos and PDFs
- Slides may also be a Quiz

Once purchased, the display of the course content will be with the full course hierarchy in a sidebar so the user can navigate through the course and view the content of each slide in the main content panel by selecting the Slide.

**Question**: There are a few choices out there, however I have seen posts about [Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og). Is this the best way to categorise the Course Content, or should I use `Taxonomy`? (As the how user view the course information will be with the full Course hierarchy in a side bar and selecting Slides will show the Slide content in the main section)

I am very familiar with Drupal basics, but I would like to know how to restrict user access to only their own purchased content?

What would be your solution to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you have a look at the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module, which may be considered as a possible alternative to the [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module, and which you seem to be familiar with already.

Have a look at my answer to "[What are the features of the Group module versus Organic Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197618/what-are-the-features-of-the-group-module-versus-organic-group-module/197622#197622)" for details about:

- How both modules compare to each other.
- Integration with various modules that you might want to take advantage of also.

## Resources

- [Community documentation for the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972).
- Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s)".
- Podcast "[Using the Group module as an Alternative to Organic Groups in Drupal 7 and 8](https://modulesunraveled.com/podcast/158-using-group-module-alternative-organic-groups-drupal-7-and-8-kristiaan-van-den-eynde)".

## Sample configuration

Below is an example of a possible configuration, which may help to get you started with possible configurations (using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module):

```
Group type ID ! Group type ! Group role ID ! Role
--------------+------------+---------------+------------
 1            ! Class      ! 3             ! Instructor
 1            ! Class      ! 4             ! Student
 2            ! Customers  ! 5             ! Lead
 2            ! Customers  ! 6             ! Prospect
 2            ! Customers  ! 7             ! Licensed Customer
 2            ! Customers  ! 8             ! Sales
 2            ! Customers  ! 9             ! Support
 2            ! Customers  ! 10            ! Accounting
 2            ! Customers  ! 11            ! R&D
 3            ! Project    ! 12            ! Project Manager
 3            ! Project    ! 13            ! Developer
 3            ! Project    ! 14            ! Customer
```

#### Group Types

The above example consists of 3 ***group types***:

- Class.
- Customers.
- Project.

#### Group Roles

For each of the 3 group types, there are specific ***Roles*** defined, some more details about some of them:

- for the *Class* group, these are the 2 roles that are configured:

  - Instructor.
  - Student.
- for the *Project* group, these are the 3 roles that are configured:

  - Project Manager.
  - Developer.
  - Customer.

These are the *Group Specific Roles*: these roles can be configured per group type and will only be available on groups of that group type. As an example, for group type "*Class*", the defined roles are **Instructor** and **Student** (which are not available for the other group types.

On top of the group specific roles, there are also *Special Global Roles*: These are the special (hardcoded) roles named **Outsider** (= a signed in user that did not join a group) and **Member**  (= a signed in user that did join a group). These cannot be defined by the Drupal administrator, and they are always available for any group. These roles can have different permissions sets for each group type. Special case: the role **Anonymous** is related to a user that is not signed.

#### Groups

Each of the configured group types can have any number of ***Groups***.

Examples of groups:

- for the *Class* group type, there could be these **Groups**:

  - Getting started with Drupal.
  - Drupal for site builders.
  - Become an expert in using the Rules module.
- for the *Customers* group type, there could be these **Groups**:

  - Service Requests.
  - Order Processing.
  - Sales Orders.
  - Relationship Management.

#### Permissions

For each of the configured group types, you can then also configure for each ***Content Type*** which ***Role*** has what kind of access (= none, view, create, edit, delete). Be aware: even though this looks similar to Drupal's permission configuration, these permissions are not the same permissions (they are specific to the Group module).

**PS**: this answer applies to either D7 or D8.

Comment: How would I then setup the hierarchy of the Couse>Moudules>Topics>Slides?

Comment: @IamOnStage Check the sample configuration I added to address your prior comment.